# javascript canvas imperfect clipping

Tags: javascript, canvas

I'm trying to draw a "ring-wedge" using the counter-clockwise method of clipping a path.

```
var cav=document.getElementById("cav");
var ct=cav.getContext("2d");

function drawWedge(r,s,e){
    ct.moveTo(250,250);
    ct.arc(250,250,r,e,s,true);
    ct.moveTo(250,250);
    ct.arc(250,250,r*0.6,s,e,false);
}
document.onmousemove=function(e){
ct.fillStyle="#ff0000";

    drawWedge(50,Math.PI/5*3,Math.PI/9*7);
    ct.fill();

}
```

You can see a fiddle here:

http://jsfiddle.net/u8vjc/2/

I'm using Chrome. If you look carefully, you can see that even if I use the same angles for both arcs, it doesn't clip cleanly. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Almost looks like it has a border or a stroke. Is there a border type property you can fiddle with?

Comment: It doesn't seem like, look at this one:http://jsfiddle.net/u8vjc/5/
So when you're moving the mouse, the imperfect clipping will pill up over time

Comment: Could be a rounding error.

Comment: @XunYang please see my answer - the solution is trivial.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To draw a wedge, you only need draw two arcs - the lines between the two arcs will be drawn in automatically:

```
function drawWedge(r, s, e){
    ct.beginPath();
    ct.arc(250, 250, r, e, s, true);
    ct.arc(250, 250, r * 0.6, s, e, false);
    ct.closePath();
}
```

You *should* call `beginPath` explicitly and *must* call `closePath` to get the final line joining the end of the second arc back to the start of the first arc.

See http://jsfiddle.net/alnitak/tEY6Z/

Comment: Thanks! Just realized that I don't need to use clipping at all... It's impossible to make two float-based shapes exactly match anyways